# A bound on powers of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality

I have come across the following ugly inequality, which I *suspect* holds for all **integer** $k \geq 1$:
$$ h(k) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-\log(k+1)^{-1}+\log(k+2)^{-1} )^n}{n^{1.5}} \leq \zeta(1.5) \frac{\log k}{\log(k+1)} $$
I've tried to prove this but (currently) to no avail. The most promising approach seemed to be induction, by comparing $h(k)$ and $h(k+1)$. I'm trying to do this by bounding the following difference which hopefully, when summed appropriately over $n$, will be small enough relative to $\frac{\log(k+1)}{\log(k+2)} - \frac{\log(k)}{\log(k+1)}$: 
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{\log(k+1)}+\frac{1}{\log(k+2)} \right)^n - \left(1-\frac{1}{\log(k+2)}+\frac{1}{\log(k+3)} \right)^n$$
But I'm bewildered. Can anyone give me a hint on an easy way to do this?

**EDIT**: original question was a little too ambitious, so I reduced it to just asking about this bound.

Comment: Are you only looking at integer $k$? Either way, you should specify.

Comment: @Chappers Yes, integer only. Thanks for the clarification! I'll edit.